# nanoScroller.js doesn't initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I have a strange problem with a website where I try to embed [nanoScroller.js](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/)

I've implemented the HTML structure and loaded the necessary js and css but it doesn't load the scroller. Has anyone an idea?

Website is: http://www.ehmesevents.de/portfolio If browser Window is wider than 980px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated docs of nanoscroller showed, that not the id of the content is needed. the class "nano-scroller" is needed. so it would look like:

```
<div id="about" class="nano">
 <div class="nano-content">
  content....
 </div>
</div>
```